# How to create a resource with spaces in file name from Annotation Processor

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

When generating resource file on compile time using `javax.annotation.processing.Processor`, not able to create files with spaces in the file name.

Simplified code to reproduce the problem:

```
public class SampleAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment env) {
    for (Element element : env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(SampleAnnotation.class)) {
        FileObject resource = processingEnv.getFiler()
                .createResource(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, "configs.generated", "file name with spaces.xml", element);
        // ...
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

On `jdk1.8.0_212.jdk` it fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid relative name: file name with spaces.xml
```

As such resource would be packaged just fine into jar if present in `src/resources`, I assume the same should be possible when auto-generated as well.

Is there a way to escape the spaces, or do something else to generate such files on compile time?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/Filer.html) of `Filer` says, "_A valid relative name must match the 'path-rootless' rule of [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), section 3.3_". The linked RFC describes URIs, which can't contain spaces, so I suppose that's where the problem comes from. Could you use another character, such as "`-`" or "`_`", instead of spaces?

Comment: @Slaw I was looking into this RFC, it allows to escape spaces with %20, but if I do that the compiler does not unescape it. Surprisingly my IDE is able to build the code from the question, and produce the files with spaces. It uses the same JDK, but apparently instrumented the compiler in some way. So it compiles fine with IDE, but not with command line / maven.

Comment: What IDE are you using? If it's Eclipse then maybe you're using Eclipse's compiler and that's why it works.

Comment: It's IntelliJ IDEA, and it clearly prints a compilation note: `Information:javac 1.8.0_212 was used to compile java sources` along with my notes that file was successfully generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a brute force approach, renaming the resulting file does the trick:

```
String nameWithoutSpaces = desiredFilename.replace(" ", "-");
FileObject resource = processingEnv.getFiler()
                .createResource(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, "configs.generated", nameWithoutSpaces, element);

Path generatedResourcePath = Paths.get(resource.toUri());
Path desiredPath = generatedResourcePath.getParent().resolve(desiredFilename);
Files.move(generatedResourcePath, desiredPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Still looking for more conventional approach.
Reference to a bug/ticket or specification note explaining why a resource can't have spaces work too.